# Spring cloud stream StreamBridge with GCP Pubsub Binder

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I use spring cloud stream in my project for publishing event to multiple kafka cluster by StreamBridge and it work well. Now i need to integrate with multi google pubsub (different projectId, credentials),i found that

```
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
```

but it not work with streamBridge cause by

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binder<?, ?, ?>' available
```

note:

- spring boot 2.7.3
- spring-cloud-gcp v3.3.0

here is my sample:

#init binder

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.pubsub-gcp.type=pubsub
spring.cloud.stream.binders.pubsub-gcp.environment.spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.project-id=
spring.cloud.stream.binders.pubsub-gcp.environment.spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.credentials.location=
```

#define function

```
spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings=update

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.update-out-0.binder=pubsub-gcp
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.update-out-0.destination=abc
```

#producer code

```
streamBridge.send("update-out-0", data)
```